# Why my circuit only draws max. of 2.8V across the electromagnet? (Circuit picture included)

Tags: pwm, arduino-uno

I created a circuit using Arduino Uno and the goal is to use pulse width modulation (PWM) so the voltage across the electromagnet decreases from maximum value to zero, and then the cycle repeats. The PWM already worked, but the maximum voltage the magnet draws is only around 2.8V. I used an external 12V DC power supply. How should I modify the circuit so I can reach voltage across the magnet close to the power supply's value, 12V? Thank you in advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: At a guess, use a smaller base resistor for your 2N2222A. You want to saturate the transistor, not use it in linear mode.  Also, there's a built-in schematic editor on this site; I would recommend using that to clean up your schematic. It's the button with the pencil and circuit components when you're editing a question.

Comment: Also, you say the power supply's 12V, but you draw ±12V, or a 24V supply. Which is it?

Comment: What is the resistance and inductance of the electromagnet. What maximum current do you expect it to draw.

Comment: the electromagnet does not draw voltage, it draws current .... my guess is that the 2.8V is the voltage, that the power supply output drops to, when it is overloaded

Comment: Please edit your question.  What is the DC resistance of the coil?  Where you say "-12V" do you mean that, or do you mean ground?  Your text implies you mean ground -- you would say "full 24V across the coil" if you're using +/-12V rails.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.  Not with those parts.

The voltage across the coil would be around 12V, if you connected to it to a 12V power supply capable of delivering the current that Ohm's law (E=IR) says will flow through the DC resistance of the coil at 12V.  Assuming (for example) that the coil has a resistance of 1 ohm, your power supply would have to supply 12V at 12A.

You need to measure the DC resistance of the coil, and find out how much current your power supply can deliver.

You probably need a bigger power supply to get a higher voltage across the coil.

Then, you will need a bigger transistor.  The 2N2222 can't handle much current.  At 12A, a 2N2222 would pretty much dissolve into smoke.

---

The thing about coils is, that the strength depends on the current.  You use ampere turns to compare coils.

A coil with 10 turns at 1A is as powerful as another coil with 100 turns at 0.1A.

You need to look at getting more current through the coil rather than at the voltage across the coil.

Comment: You cannot assume that the OP is using a \$12\Omega\$ coil, though.

Comment: I didn't.  I made a couple of examples.